# Prove that $x^p - t $ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)[x]$.

Tags: galois-theory

Prove that the polynomial $x^p - t$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)[x]$.  (Here $t$ is a formal variable).

---

I know how to prove by Eisenstein's (for integral domains and ideals). However, my Professor said that this can also be solved by first constructing a field extension in which the polynomial splits. Can someone give me a hint?

If I let $u$ be a $p$-th root of unity of $t$, then I can construct a field extension $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ in which $x^p - t = x^p - u^p = (x - u)^p$ (true by binomial expansion in a field of characteristic $p$) splits. I should be able to prove $x^p - t$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ here. If there were a monic polynomial of degree $r$ less than $p$ for which $u$ is a root, then $u^r$ would not be in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$. So $x^p - t$ must be the minimal polynomial.

I think the proof should follow from here somehow, but am not sure. Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have all the elements the last thing to show is that the minimal polynomial $\mu$ of $u$ (over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$) is $x^p-t$. Because $\mu$ is minimal we muste have $\mu(x)=(x-u)^r$ with $r\leq p$, if we have $r<p$ then :

$$\mu(x)=(x-u)^r=u^r+ru^{r-1}.x+x^2P(x)$$

But now $\mu(x)$ must be a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)[x]$ i.e. each of its coefficient must be in  $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$. In particular you must have :

$$ru^{r-1}\in \mathbb{F}_p(t)$$

and because $r<p$ and $u^r\in\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, you must have :

$$u\in \mathbb{F}_p(t)$$

which is false because $t$ has not such root in the field $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$.

Comment: Thank you -- Could you just clarify what r and P(x) are?

Comment: I'll edit directly my answer...

Comment: Here $r$ is the degree of $\mu$ (I corrected it now it must be clear).

Comment: Yes this makes sense to me now. thank you!

Comment: On the other hand, if you develop $(x-u)^r$ you will get some constant coefficient in $x$, then a coefficient in front of $x$ ($ru$) and something I do not need to explicit because that is divisible by $x^2$, that's what the $P$ stands for.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Does $u^r+ru.x+x^2P(x)$ mean $u^r+rxu^{r-1}+x^2 P(x)$?
Did you use $u^r\in \Bbb{F}_p(t)$ and $u^{r-1}\in \Bbb{F}_p(t)$ to get $u=u^r/u^{r-1}\in \Bbb{F}_p(t)$?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$t$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_p[t]$, and thus, you can conclude by Eisenstein criterion.

Comment: $t$ is prime and irreducible in UFD $\Bbb{F}_p[t]$.
Note that $-t\in \langle t\rangle$, $1\notin \langle t\rangle$ and $-t\notin \langle t\rangle^2$.
By the generalized Eisenstein's criterion, 
$x^p-t$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_p[t][x]$.
By Gauss's lemma, 
$x^p-t$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_p(t)[x]$.

Comment: A doubt: $<t>^2:=\left\{(th(t))^2:h(t)\in\mathbb{F}_{p}[t]\right\}?$

If $-t\in <t>^2$ then $-t=t^2h(t)^2$ now $1=2+deg(h(t))^2$ then $0=1+deg(h(t)^2)$ a contradiction. Therefore $-t\in <t>^2$. It is correct?